# XML Serialization of nested classes having Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, idictionary

I am trying to XML-serialize a nested class. Both classes have dictionaries which I am serializing using this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

Serialization works fine but the nested class doesn't get de-serialized.
Can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question, you can post it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IXmlSerializable on the class that you need to serialize.  It's a bit of extra work, but it provides a much nicer way to control XML output for your classes.

If you do this, serializing a dictionary should not be a issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
Actually my custom Dictionary serialization was wrong. I corrected it according to the list I have in question and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization does not serialize nested classes. It only serializes member fields/properties of a class. If you want to serialize a nested class, you should have a field of the nested class type in the parent class.